# Computation of the divisor class group of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3+y^3-1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is:

**What is the divisor class group of $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^3+y^3-1)$?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Actually, $x^3+y^3=1$ is the equation of an elliptic curve. We can rewrite it, say, as $y^2=x^3-\frac{2}{3}x+\frac{23}{108}$. For the elliptic curve $E$ the Picard group is $E(K)\oplus \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the elliptic curve defined by $x^3+y^3-z^3=0$ in the projective plane. Then, the class group of $X$ is $A=X\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ ($X$ has a natural abelian group structure). Then the class group of your curve is got by putting $z=1$ and thus it is the quotient of the above group with kernel given by $z=0$ which are the three points $x^3+y^3=0$. Thus the class group is the quotient of $A$ by the group generated by these three elements. In particular, it is divisible and uncountable.